# Mostrar os dados do label em radio em vez de texto

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Tenho esta consulta e mostro desta forma:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$inicio = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['data']);

$sql = "SELECT `regOratorio`.`DataEntrada`,
`regOratorio`.`Utente`,
`regOratorio`.`Estado`,
`regOratorio`.`Observacao`,
`regOratorio`.`Colaborador`
FROM `centrodb`.`regOratorio` WHERE DataEntrada = '$inicio'";

 $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
  echo 'There are no results for your search';
  } else {
 echo '<form name="customer_details" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return alguma_funcao()">';    
 }
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<table cellspacing='10'>";
 echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";   

echo "<label>Utente</label>"; 
echo "<input id='' type='text' value='".$row['Utente']."'";  

echo "<label>Estado</label>"; 
echo "<input id='' type='text' value='".$row['Estado']."'";  

echo "<label>Observacao</label>"; 
echo "<input type='text' value='".$row['Observacao']."'";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</fieldset>";

echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<table cellspacing='10'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<input type='text' value='".$row['Colaborador']."'";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</fieldset>";

 }
echo "</form>";
mysqli_close($conn);
} 
else
{
?>
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>Enter Student Number:</label>
  <input name="data" type="date" placeholder="Type Here">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

```
<?php
}
?>
```

O label do **Estado** está como `type='text'`, mas queria que ele mostrasse os dados da consulta como `type='radio'`, onde tenho dois estados (**Presente** e **Ausente**), pretendo que apreçam os dois e que apareça seleccionado o que foi registado na tabela e quero a possibilidade de editar esse campo (**estado**) e o da **Observação**. É possível?

Comment: bruno você que motre apenas 1 estado ou todos? não seria melhor em um compro select?

Comment: só tenho dois estados, o presente e ausente, quero mostrar os dois e que apareça seleccionado o que está registado na tabela, e quero dar a possibilidade de editar esse campo (estado) e o da observação, é possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom vamos lá,

basta alterar este teu código:

```
echo "<label>Estado</label>"; 
echo "<input id='' type='text' value='".$row['Estado']."'";
```

por isso:

```
echo "<label>Estado</label>"; 
echo "<input type='radio' value='presente' " . ( ($row['Estado']=='presente') ? 'checked' : '' ) ."> Presente";
echo "<input type='radio' value='ausente' " . ( ($row['Estado']=='ausente') ? 'checked' : '' ) ."> Ausente";
```

O PhP permite você escrever um if como este:

```
($row['Estado'] == ausente)?
 'checked' : ''>Ausente"
```

que está dizendo se o seu estado ($row['Estado']) for igual a ausente, então marca esse radio como `checked` se não nao coloca nada.

acho que vale te mostrar como ficaria com um select combo.

**Um exemplo visual de como ficaria com select e radio**

```html
Estados com select: <br>
<select name="estados">
    <option value="sp">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="mg">Minas Gerais </option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

Estados radio: <br>
<input type="radio" name="sp" value="sp" checked>São Paulo<br>
<input type="radio" name="rj" value="rj">Rio de Janeiro<br>
<input type="radio" name="mg" value="mg"> Minas Gerais
```

Comment: jovem, acabei de conferir aqui e tem um erro de sintaxe, estou alterando agora e tente de novo

Comment: Se colocar como disse dá o erro 500 na página, então efetuei uma pequena alteração, que foi `echo "<input type='radio' value='Presente' ('".$row['Estado']."' == Presente)? 'checked' : ''> Presente";` `echo "<input type='radio' value='ausente' ('".$row['Estado']."' == ausente)? 'checked' : ''> Ausente";`, mas não fica nenhum preenchido, ficam vazios

Comment: @BrunoPinto eu alterei o código, coloca agora o código que eu coloquei, e me fala como está salvo ausente e presente no seu banco. assim: PRESENTE ou assim presente ou Presente

Comment: Com a sua alteração já não dá erro, mas os `radios` ficam vazios, não vai buscar a informação à tabela da base de dados.

Comment: a informação ja está vindo do bano nessa variavel $row['Estado'], mas ele só vai ser checked se for igual a presente ou ausente, ( se na tabela do seu banco estiver salvo em maiusculo por exemplo Presente ou Presente. entao ele não vai marcar checked, por isso que perguntei como está cadastrado no banco, tem como dizer:?

Comment: Bruno o if compara uma coisa com a outra. isso => 'Presente' é diferente disso 'presente' que tb é diferente disso => 'PRESENTE'

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado, o problema era mesmo esse. Agora como edito este campo Estado case tenha necessidade de alterar?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72713/discussion-between-julio-henrique-and-bruno-pinto).

Comment: Estou no chat, mas deixo aqui o que pretendo: **Vamos imaginar que quem fez o registo se enganou e colocou o cliente presente mas afinal ele não esteve presente, quero ter a possibilidade de alterar o registo**